# http get method is not working in for loop in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

hi all i am using `angularjs`  `http` get method i get the values dynamically based on my loop  but i am not able to get the value from `http` get help how to do this and solve the problem

```
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    var stream =i;
    $http.get('/ViewGetBUMaterialStream/' + stream  ).then(function (response) {
                   $scope.ViewStreams[i] = response.data;
    });
}
```

Comment: You should probably post a bit more, oh also if you actually use + Stream that variable is not defined here, why not use the i there too

Comment: Problem is, by the time all your HTTP requests finish, `i` is and will only be the value `4`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: you need to learn javascript at first, instead of start from angular...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `let` keyword. This is a usually problem for [closures.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

The let statement declares a block scope local variable, optionally initializing it to a value.

```
for(let i=0;i<4;i++){
    var stream =i;
    $http.get('/ViewGetBUMaterialStream/' + stream  ).then(function (response) {
               $scope.ViewStreams[i] = response.data;
    });
}
```

Another method is to use a [Immediately-invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

```
(function(i){
  $http.get('/ViewGetBUMaterialStream/' + Stream  ).then(function (response) 
     {
        $scope.ViewStreams[i] = response.data;
     });
})(i);
```

Comment: How the let keyword will fix the issue. And to use `let` he need es6.

Comment: `let` keyword declares a block scope local variable, optionally initializing it to a value and that's you needed.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused because of javascript. Unfortunately, javascript does not have a scope for a loop, variables declared in a for loop are in a function scope. You should use an anonymous inner function and pass the value of i to that function block.

```
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    var stream =i;
    (function(i){
      $http.get('/ViewGetBUMaterialStream/' + Stream  ).then(function (response) {
                   $scope.ViewStreams[i] = response.data;
      });
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: _"javascript does not have a scope for a loop"_ It does.

Comment: @zeroflagL Confusion should be because of my poor choice of words. Javascript does not have a separate scope for loops. Am I missing something?

Comment: _"Am I missing something?"_ Yes. JavaScript does have a separate scope for loops (iteration scope). But it requires the usage of `let`.

Comment: @zeroflagL Sorry man. I assumed that we are still in es5 era.

Answer (score 1):

try this to bind `i` to your callbacks.

```
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
  var stream =i;
  $http.get('/ViewGetBUMaterialStream/' + stream  ).then(function (response) {
    $scope.ViewStreams[i] = response.data;
  }.bind(i));
}
```